# Access entity through intermediate table with EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm currently using EF Core and I have 3 tables

```
Campaign
CampaignStation
Station
```

`CampaignStation` is a intermediate table between `Campaign` and `Station`

**Campaign table:**

```
public class Campaign
{
    public int CampaignId { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;

    public ICollection<CampaignStation> Stations { get; set; } = new List<CampaignStation>();

 }

public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Campaign> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(x => x.CampaignId);
        builder.Property(x => x.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(250);
        builder.HasMany(x => x.Stations).WithOne(y => y.Campaign);
    }
```

So one campaign can have multiple Stations, that is why I have an **intermediate table** as:

```
public class CampaignStation
{
    public int CampaignStationId { get; set; }

    public int? CampaignId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CampaignId))]
    public Campaign? Campaign { get; set; }

    public int? StationId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(StationId))]
    public Station? Station { get; set; }
}


public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CampaignStation> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("CampaignStations");
        builder.HasKey(x => x.CampaignStationId);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Campaign);
        builder.HasOne(x => x.Station);
    }
```

**Get Service:**

```
return await _db.Campaigns
            .Include(a => a.Agency)
            .Include(s => s.Stations)
            .ToListAsync();
```

But Stations entity always come null, it is getting the id of intermediate table as following picture:

[image]

Why I can not access Station Entity?

Comment: `.Include(s => s.Stations).ThenInclude(cs => cs.Station)`.

Answer (score 0):

As the comment of @vernou, I only need to add the intermediate table then use `ThenInclude` to include the Station table as:

```
return await _db.Campaigns
            .Include(a => a.Agency)
            .Include(s => s.Stations)
            .ThenInclude(cs => cs.Station)
            .ToListAsync();
```